# Generate a flat case class from a schema avro which has more then 254 fileds

Tags: java, scala, avro, avro4s, avrohugger

I am working on a flat schema, there is no nested type inside, and it has more than 254 fields.

**Goal**: What I want to do is to **automatically** convert this kind of schema to a flat case class by the specific generator

**Issue**: a parameter list's length cannot exceed 254 in JVM

What I tried => use the plugins *sbt-avrohugger* and *sbt-avro4s*, but they didn't work so well.

Q: Is there a way to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is fix in avro 1.8.1

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1642

if is possible  use avro 1.8.1 or higher, it will solve your issue

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I think their spec should specify this, it is important